# How to run an app with Android ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to test my Android app on Eclipse but when I press on `Run As...` and then on `Android Application` it says: `Android libary projects cannot be launched.` What should I do to run it?

thank you for answers :)

P.S.: I'm not very good in English ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot launch an Android Library project. However, if its not library project and by mistake you have marked "IsLibrary" then uncheck the same option by
right-click in your project and select Properties. In the Properties window -> "Android" -> uncheck the option "is Library" and apply -> Click "ok" to close the properties window.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably have your project defined as a library ..uncheck the Is Library checkbox in your project properties.  So right click on the head of the project and go to Properties.  Click on Android on the left and look for is Library:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project and go to your project properties:

[image]

Now uncheck the `is Library` checkbox:

[image]